# How many ways we can install apk on device

Tags: android, jenkins, adb, apk

i want to know apart from adb command ,file manager and installing apk from email and creating own apk with the help of Jenkins,is there are any other ways that we can install apk on device.

Answer (score 0):

4 different ways to Install **APK** on android devices:

1) Google Play Store

2) Downloading APK & Installing it by Opening
    It.

3) Installing App APK via ADB Usb Cable Connection.

4)
    Installing App via App Sync on Google Play Store.

You can read more about [here](http://www.technorange.com/2015/12/4-different-ways-to-install-apps-apks-on-android-devices/)

Comment: i m sorry to mention ,its about .apk file during build phase